# i need to turn this select to a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im struggling whit this, i have to change a select form for a checkbox form
i can make the visuals change but the checkbox doesnt work like the select

this is the select

```
<div className="form-group">
<label forhtml="road-typeControlSelect">Flags</label>
<select name="flags" value={flags}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-control" id="road-typeControlSelect">
    <option value={0}>All</option>
    <option value={1}>Tunnel</option>
    <option value={16}>Unpaved</option>
    <option value={32}>Headlights required</option>
    <option value={128}>Next to carpool/HOV/bus lane</option>
</select>
```

and this is what i have done so far whit the checkbox

```
                <div name="flags" value={flags}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-control" id="road-typeControlSelect">
                        <label forhtml="road-typeControlSelect">Flags</label>
                        <div className="form-group form-check">
                            <input value={0} type="checkbox" name="All"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-check-input" />
                            <label className="form-check-label">All</label>
                        </div>  
                        <div className="form-group form-check">
                            <input value={1} type="checkbox" name="Tunnel" onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-check-input"/>
                            <label className="form-check-label">Tunnel</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group form-check">
                            <input value={16} type="checkbox" name="Unpaved"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-check-input" />
                            <label className="form-check-label">Unpaved</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group form-check">
                            <input value={32} type="checkbox" name="Headlights required"   onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-check-input"/>
                            <label className="form-check-label">Headlights required</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group form-check">
                            <input value={128} type="checkbox" name="Next to carpool/HOV/bus lane"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-check-input"/>
                            <label className="form-check-label">Next to carpool/HOV/bus lane</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this is my handler metod

```
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        filterObj:{...this.state.filterObj,...{[name]: value}}
    });
}
```

i would apreciate help on this topic. im using reactjs but this seems to be more pure javascript problem

Comment: The name of each checkbox should be `flags`.

Comment: i tried that and nothing happens

Comment: you are right about the radio buttons since for now i want to send only one value at time. i deleted the onChange on the div, and the inputs has already the onChange variable, still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular question so I decided to make two examples for handling multiple checkboxes and a single checkbox `'radio inputs'`

> No need to put onChange for each input as you are defined an onChange for the parent div

**Multiple Checkboxes**

```
   <div name="flags" onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-control" id="road-typeControlSelect">
      <label forhtml="road-typeControlSelect">Flags</label>
      <div className="form-group form-check">
        <input value={0} type="checkbox" name="flags" className="form-check-input" />
        <label className="form-check-label">All</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group form-check">
        <input value={1} type="checkbox" name="flags"  className="form-check-input" />
        <label className="form-check-label">Tunnel</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group form-check">
        <input value={16} type="checkbox" name="flags" className="form-check-input" />
        <label className="form-check-label">Unpaved</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group form-check">
        <input value={32} type="checkbox" name="flags"  className="form-check-input" />
        <label className="form-check-label">Headlights required</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group form-check">
        <input value={128} type="checkbox" name="flags"  className="form-check-input" />
        <label className="form-check-label">Next to carpool/HOV/bus lane</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then in `handleInputChange` function, checking the input value if exist will delete it or if not will add it

```
  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let checkedBox = e.target.value;
    if(this.state.flages.indexOf(checkedBox) !== -1){
      console.log(checkedBox, 'deleted!')
      this.setState(prevState=> ({
        flages: prevState.flages.filter(d => d !== checkedBox)
      })) // deleting the value from array if exist
    }else{
      this.setState(prevState => ({ flages: [...prevState.flages, checkedBox] }));
    }
  }
```

[image: Edit Handle multiple checkBox]

**Signal Checkbox**

> Change `checkbox` to `radio` of input type
>
> All the input name attribute should be the same

```
<div name="flags" onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-control" id="road-typeControlSelect">
  <label forhtml="road-typeControlSelect">Flags</label>
  <div className="form-group form-check">
    <input value={0} type="radio" name="flags" className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label">All</label>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group form-check">
    <input value={1} type="radio" name="flags"  className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label">Tunnel</label>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group form-check">
    <input value={16} type="radio" name="flags" className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label">Unpaved</label>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group form-check">
    <input value={32} type="radio" name="flags"  className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label">Headlights required</label>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group form-check">
    <input value={128} type="radio" name="flags"  className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label">Next to carpool/HOV/bus lane</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In `handleInputChange` Function

```
  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let checkedBox = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ flages: checkedBox})
  }
```

[image: Edit Handle radio buttons]

Comment: tried bot, none works, the first one throws an error "this.state.flages is undefined", and the second one, just dont filter the info, it just mark it if its selected

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it works, you are my new god now, i praise you

Comment: I'm glad to help